# Internal server error on Azure web site after enabling EF code first migrations

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I had a very simple MVC5 web app (VS 2013 RC) deploying into an Azure web site. It worked until I checked the "Execute Code First Migrations" in the Publish Web dialog. Now, I'm getting an internal server error when I hit the site. If I uncheck the "Execute Code First Migrations" check box in the Publish Web dialog, the web app works as expected. In the course of troubleshooting the problem, I connected directly to the Azure-hosted database from my local machine and ran the Enable-Migrations and Update-Database commands, though I'm not sure if that was necessary or not.

Do you know what the purpose of that check box is and how automatic code first migrations should be enabled in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue last week when I enabled code-first migrations and re-published a site that had been working prior to this.  What I observed SEEMED to indicate this:

If you have that checked, when your site initially starts to run, it will run the code-first migration.  Since mine had some "create table" for the newly created table, it ran that code.  Unfortunately, I had published an existing database with SQL Server 2012 up to Azure and that table had data in it.  So, the code first migration was causing it to drop that table and recreate it.

I'm not 100% sure that is what was happening but I believe it is.  Mainly because when I went into the SQL Server Management Studio and looked at the data for my table on Azure, it was empty after launching the site.

To confirm, I republished my site and confirmed there was data in the database table.  Ran the site and it vanished.

So inevitably, I just unchecked that box and republished my site and database.  Once I did that, the data was there and the site still worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue. It turned out it was because I had added Entity Framework to a class library via Nuget, but not added it to the web project. This worked locally, but caused the symptoms you described when I published to Azure.